# StringTemplate on C#: does it really work or is it completely buggy?

Tags: c#, .net, antlr

I have tried without success to add anttlr.StringTemplate namespace to c# cs file it cannot find it.

Is this package for .net http://www.stringtemplate.org/download.html completely buggy ? If yes how can the author not even test this very basic stuff ?

Update: finally I found it. Yes the link from the official front page is yes Buggy! I have downloaded from another link http://www.antlr.org/download/CSharp and now it works. They didn't even check what a shame.

Comment: Try: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr3CSharpReleases

Comment: (The namespace is Antlr4.StringTemplate for v4, the "finally found" link appears to be for StringTemplate v3, not v4? Anyway, the downloads at the link about "works fine" here.)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are writing C# code (not Java), make sure the first letter of the namespace is capitalized, and that you only have one 't' in Antlr:

Correct: `Antlr.StringTemplate`
Incorrect: `anttlr.StringTemplate`

See http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Five+minute+Introduction for details.

Comment: @user310291 - OK. Your post showed it as a lower case 'a', hence the recommendation. Since Intellisense is showing the information, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference in the project as well.